# Как в lxml Python передать из переменной название файла?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Имеется данный код:

```
file_events = "1.xml"
tree = etree.parse(file_events)
```

При попытке выполнить код выдает ошибку:

> tree = etree.parse(file_events) File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in
>   lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:79720) File "parser.pxi", line
>   1782, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:115914) File
>   "parser.pxi", line 1808, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
>   (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:116264) File "parser.pxi", line 1712, in
>   lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:115152) File
>   "parser.pxi", line 1115, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
>   (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:109849) File "parser.pxi", line 573, in
>   lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
>   (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103323) File "parser.pxi", line 683, in
>   lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:104977) File
>   "parser.pxi", line 613, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
>   (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103886) lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Premature
>   end of data in tag value line 915, line 915, column 43

Но если вместо переменной указать имя файла, то все проходит на ура. В чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема решена. Просто я это файл при предыдущем действии с ним забыл закрыть.